# how to make a menu in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently making a discord bot using discord.js and i am trying to make a menu command so when a user types [prefix]menu it sends a picture of the menu
i can do that easily but i am trying to make it multipaged, i know i could just make a menu1, menu2 and menu3 command but id like to have a command saying nextpage and previouspage this is what i have so far but it doesn't work and there is no errors

```
      if (command === "menu") {
          output()
            message.channel.send({file: './images/menu1.png'});
            curPage = 1;
        }

        if (command === "next page") {
          output()
                curPage++;
                if(curPage >= 3) {
                  output()
                    curPage = 3; message.channel.send("You're on the last page!");
                }
            } else if (command === "previous page") {
              output()
                curPage--;
                if(curPage <= 0) {
                  output()
                    curPage = 1; message.channel.send("You're on the first page!");
                }
                message.channel.send({file: `./images/menu${curPage}.png`});
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) instead.

A [`collect`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) event would be emitted when a user reacts to the targeted message.

Example:

```
const collector = message.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => 
    user.id === message.author.id &&
    reaction.emoji.name === "◀" ||
    reaction.emoji.name === "▶" ||
    reaction.emoji.name === "❌"
).once("collect", reaction => {
    const chosen = reaction.emoji.name;
    if(chosen === "◀"){
        // Prev page
    }else if(chosen === "▶"){
        // Next page
    }else{
        // Stop navigating pages
    }
    collector.stop();
});
```

[image: Reaction]

Docs: [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector), [Reaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction), [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this, would be with .awaitMessages?

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages

It might be worth trying something along these lines, however I'm not 100% sure about how to await multiple times for paging back and forth... I'd be interested in seeing someone elses solution for this.

For example:

```
if (command === "menu") {
        message.channel.send({file: './images/menu1.png'});
        .then(() => {
          message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'next', {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time'],
          })
          .then((collected) => {
              message.channel.send({file: './images/menu2.png'});
            })
            .catch(() => {
              // Do something with error 
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Another, less efficient, way to achieve this might be having the menu command send the image for a set amount of time and then having the bot delete the message. You could then have separate commands for 'next' or 'previous' that only work before the message is deleted as well as refresh the timer and simply delete the image and send the new menu page that was requested.

Comment: An alternative to awaitMessages is to use a [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector)